# CheckBox with SimpleCursorAdapter in ListActivity (ListView)

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, listactivity

Hey all, I know there are a number of tutorials of implementing a custom adapter, but I am not convinced that this is right for me.  I have a list view of a custom item layout consisting of two TextViews and a CheckBox.  I have the following code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                long rowid) {

            CheckBox c = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.item_chkbox);
            c.setChecked(!c.isChecked());
            String n = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_charName)).getText().toString();
            String p = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_playerName)).getText().toString();
            ...
```

When I tap on an item in the list, a check box is fired and is checked, but it's not the right one.  It's not random, either.  The CheckBox that is fired is always on the opposite side, mirrored at the center of the list.  For example, if I had a list of:

0 1 2 3 4

And tapped "0", 4's check would fire.  If I tapped 1, 3's check would fire.  If I tap 2, 2's check fires.  Even stranger, if I tap 0 twice, 3 checks, then 0 checks.  Tap a third time, 3 unchecks.   A forth - 0 unchecks.  This continues in pattern with all cases.  I can't quite figure out what is going on.

Please note that the strings n and p both come out correctly.  In other words, tapping 0 would retrieve the string for "name" in the corresponding list item.  It's only the CheckBoxes which are out of whack.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm... what's the rest of the onItemClick method? What does your Adapter store?

Comment: Well you know I searched around for a couple days and apparently didn't do a very good job, I came across someone who had a very similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834142/android-simplecursoradapter-usage
and I am now trying to follow their solution.  I can't figure out where their use of the class "EventDbAdapter" came from though.

Answer (score 1):

I have met your problem, and my solution is removing all things that relative to multiple choice of your list view, such that android:CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, android:choiceMode,.... Just try it!

Answer (score 1):

The blame should go to `ListView` because when you scroll the custom `ListView` you should **override the `getView(...)` of the adapter**. API docs say the view is recycled. As a result, the state of the previous view should be saved. For example, whether the `CheckBox` is checked. If you restore the state, `ListView` will show as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but I think this should work: in `onItemClick` method, instead of using `view` object to find the `CheckBox`, try using `ListView.getChildAt(position)`.